# Media Capture Native Plugin Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am making a ionic 3 application in which i want enable the user to capture pictures and videos. So i used the media capture plugin, once i capture a image or video i get the `MediaFile[]` promise in return. Now when i am trying to display that image as a preview in `ion-img` tag with `[src] = mediaFile[‘0’].fullPath`. it is not displaying the image.

please tell me if my appraoch is wrong then what should i do.

here is the capturing part:

```
this.mediaCapture.captureImage()
  .then(

    (data: MediaFile[]) => {
         this.navCtrl.push('NewPostPage', {
         mediaFile : data
         })
    },
    (err: CaptureError) => console.error(err)
  );
```

here is the html of newpostpage:

```
<ion-content padding>

  <ion-img [src] = 'image'></ion-img>

</ion-content>
```

here is the `.ts` file of newpostpage:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MediaFile } from '@ionic-native/media-capture';

/**
 * Generated class for the NewPostPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-new-post',
  templateUrl: 'new-post.html',
})
export class NewPostPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  mediaFile: MediaFile[] = this.navParams.get('mediaFile');
  image: string = this.mediaFile['0'].fullPath;


  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad NewPostPage');
    console.log(this.image);    
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey don't know if you are still having this issue.

The way I solved this issue is by printing the file path in the console and then I attempted to remove different parts of it and see what works.

Specifically what worked was removing the `"file:"` prefix like so:

```
self.media.captureVideo().then((data: MediaFile[]) => {
                let file = data.pop();
                let path = file.fullPath.replace('file:', '');
                resolve(path);
            }, err => {
                console.dir(err);
                reject(err);
            });
```

I could then use the path to transfer/play the file.

Comment: actually the problem was, the path returned by the plugin was wrong.. i used the camera plugin for images and media capture plugin for videos. the captureImage() function of mediaCapture plugin was returning false path.

Comment: @FaizanUllah the path isn't wrong, it's just a different path format that could be used within the media plugin. For other purposes, the path has to be different, that's what I attempt to describe in my answer by saying that: editing the returned path was the solution.